# Missing faces on a exported model when using transparency

Tags: export, transparency, faces

I've come upon a problem I can't resolve. It happened to me once before, but I can't remember how I handled it.

I've created a wine glass model in Blender - low and highpoly meshes, unwrapped it, then used Substance Painter to bake maps and texture paint.

So far everything was working fine, till I imported my lowpoly model to engine where it will be showcased. When using transparency polygons start to disappear.
[image: Model in threeJS - without and with error]

In Blender I checked everything I could think of - I recalculated normals, made sure they face correct direction, erased custom split normals, added weighted normals modifier, exported in different formats. Nothing helped. Just before this wine glass I made a common glass and everything was working ok.

The engine Im importing to is threeJS, but Im still asking for a help here, not threeJS forum. I don't have any access to the engine options, can just import models and textures, but somehow resolved this issue in past, so the mistake is somewhere on Blender's side.

I attach blend file - https://we.tl/t-Nfk9H8XV7z

Thanks

Update 1
Just noticed that this bug also occurs in Substance Painter, weird I didn't spot it ealier. Just fyi - I export fbx to work in Painter and obj to threeJS.

[image: Missing faces in Substance Painter]

Update 2
I managed to visualize the problem in Blender. To see it - open blend file I attached, change to Eevee, add material and change Blend Mode to Alpha Blend.

[image: Missing faces in Blender]

Comment: So there is not actually geometry missing, just transparency issue, right? FBX has quite a lot of issues, but if you tried other formats it doesn't seems to be the case. In the whole process you'r using just lowly version, right? SubsPainter - you just open exported fbx and you see transparent as in your screen, right? Because I cant confirm that with blender3.3 > SP1.7 https://imgur.com/hmuqut2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could form the question clearer, you are right. 
Yes, I use highpoly only for baking, everywhere else I use lowpoly. In Subs the issue doesn't show till I add a layer with opacity different than 100%. 
I managed to visualize the problem in Blender (up in the post), but can't find the reason why model is acting like that. 
Imo, it is not a transparency problem, because it occurs on multiple formats and in more than 1 rendering engine.

Comment: Those are "Backfaces" ... but what cause them? Hmm ... try to disable "Show Backface" option, if does it make any difference. I mean it make a difference in Eevee https://cgcookie.com/lessons/show-backface-in-eevee ... but I'm not sure about exported model since this affects probably just visibility in blender. I know how "Backface Culling" works, but not this "Show" thing. But maybe it is parametr that goes with export so there is a chance it will have influence. Better than nothing now.

Comment: It indeed works in Eevee, but doesn't help when importing to threeJS. But when following your suggestion I noticed something. For me it appears that model normals are somehow "corrupted", despite all of fixes they still have bad direction and it shows when using transparency. But why there are no shading issues on surface?

Comment: I don't think I can help more sorry ... even default Cube with that settings showing it in a weird way for me. More clearly visible when subdivisions few times ...  https://imgur.com/l8uvErd ... Since we know it comes from blender would be helpful to rewrote your Q to make it shorter and clear for newcomers just things that really matters now. And I suggest to delete also comments so it is clear here is not solution.

Comment: So it appears that blend file might be corrupted.
Anyway, I will wait for other answers till end of weekend, I would like to know how to fix it when it occurs with more complex model.
If I won't find a way to fix it, I will do as you say and rewrite the Q.